# introduce C++ class to Octave

Tags: c++, octave

I went through the web and did not find a proper introduction on how to introduce a C++ class to Octave. What I want to do is something like

C++:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int n) {...}
    ~Foo() {...}
    void Print() {...}
};
```

Octave:

```
> foo = Foo(9);
> foo.Print();
```

In addition, I also would like to know about read-in Octave vector, matrix in C++ code (2-way integration).

Comment: https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Getting-Started-with-Oct_002dFiles.html https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Calling-Octave-Functions-from-Oct_002dFiles.html#Calling-Octave-Functions-from-Oct_002dFiles

Comment: @CrisLuengo The question is formulated implicitly. That is "How to introduce a C++ class to Octave?"

Comment: As I said, a tutorial on how to do this is out of scope for Stack Overflow. There’s a difference between answering a question and writing a text book on a broad subject. You are asking us to write a text book.

Comment: well, @CrisLuengo maybe you miss my point. I just ask for an introductory example, if there is and someone is so kind enough to contribute to save other's time. No need a textbook for that. If, in the future, I could make a small example, I could add it here though.

Comment: @kstn I see both yours and Cris' points. Personally I think you're both right for the wrong reasons, hahah. To elaborate: I think your question comes from prior assumptions of how octave works / should work, that are not correct. Providing an example of how you would use such a class _in octave_ would clarify what those assumptions are, and give us an "attack surface" to answer specifically, by clarifying what the mistaken assumptions are. I will attempt an answer below that attacks "one possible interpretation" of what I think your assumptions may be and why this assumption does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that are backwords in your question, which to me implies you have certain assumptions on how octave (and specifically the octave-C++ interface) works, which do not apply.

E.g., if you do "Foo(9)", what is the resulting object *in octave terms*? Is it an octave object? Of course not; there's no reason a c++ class would be identical to an octave class (and it would be a rather big assumption to assume that octave devs have gone to the trouble to make octave objects identically compatible with c++ objects -- a task so monumental that no other language has attempted it).

Secondly, even if you did manage to somehow create a representation of a C++ object in octave ... where does it live in memory, and how do its functions operate? C++ is a compiled, static language, octave is an interpreted, dynamic language. So, really, the question of "importing" a c++ class into octave does not make as much sense as you think it does.

What you *should* be asking, is if there is an interface that allows you to do things with C++ classes, in octave.

And the answer is yes. Sort of. There is no interface for c++ classes "specifically", but there is a c++ interface in general.

So, depending on how you'd like to use the c++ class object in octave, you can use the octave-c++ interface to create a suitable API for your c++ class's functionality.

For example, if you need to have an "object" of some sort, within octave, that has methods that can be called, then an obvious choice would be to create an *octave* class, and simply make sure its methods are delegated to .oct/.mex files (which are compiled c++ code).

If you stick to the so-called ["old style"](https://octave.org/doc/v6.3.0/Object-Oriented-Programming.html#Object-Oriented-Programming) of object oriented programming in octave (which I actually prefer), then this is as simple as replacing your function files inside the "@" folder with .oct files (ok, in theory, you can do this with the new 'classdef' style too if you want :p).

It would also imply that, since octave methods implicitly pass the octave object with them, your C++ interface would have to recreate the C++ equivalent object in the c++ code, and THEN perform the appropriate method call and return the result (which could be a new c++ object, which you'd then convert to an octave object, and return that, in order to represent changed state).

Alternatively, if all you need is to use some c++ class function "under the hood", while inside the c++ environment, but from an octave point of view all you really care about is passing some "initialization" parameters, and getting back a result, then you don't need an octave object at all, and all you need is a simple .oct based function, which takes some (initialization) parameters, passes them to the c++ interface, and simply "happens" to use c++ classes under the hood before returning a value to your octave workspace.

---

<sub>PS. I didn't talk about the "vector interface" addendum in your question, because that is covered at reasonable depth in the documentation, as mentioned by Cris. See https://octave.org/doc/v6.3.0/Matrices-and-Arrays-in-Oct_002dFiles.html#Matrices-and-Arrays-in-Oct_002dFiles in particular, if interested. The full C++ API is available at: https://octave.org/doxygen/stable/</sub>

Comment: Nice. You’re a much more patient man than I am. :)

Comment: There’s another possibility, that much more complex. You’d need all method calls to be funneled through a single (private) mex/oct file. This next/oct file would contain a static list of C++ objects created, the Octave object would contain a reference to the C++ object (e.g. the list index). I guess this is useful only when the C++ object owns resources (an open file, a window on a screen, data that is hard to reproduce, etc).

Comment: "You’re a much more patient man than I am": I believe the word you're looking for is "procrastinator", Cris! Hahahah.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic implementation:

In C++ you need to define a wrapper class, here is named `octave_Foo`, that contains a `std::shared_ptr` to a `Foo` object and redirects calls to it.
It should be subclass of `octave_base_value` and should have a constructor that takes no arguments. Also it should have a member function named `is_defined`. All other member functions are used to redirect calls. At the end of the class definition use two macros `DECLARE_OV_BASE_TYPEID_FUNCTIONS_AND_DATA` and `DEFINE_OV_TYPEID_FUNCTIONS_AND_DATA`.
After that use `DEFUN_DLD` macro to define an `oct` function , here is named `Foo_dispatch`, that gets a method name as string and other arguments and calls the proper method of `octave_Foo` class.
Save the C++ file as `Foo_dispatch.cc` and use `mkoctfile Foo_dispatch.cc` to compile it as `Foo_dispatch.oct`.

In Octave you need to define a class `Foo` that is subclass of `handle`. Its methods call `Foo_dispatch` with the proper arguments.

Note that `Foo` is subclass of `handle` because the C++ class `octave_Foo` has reference semantics instead of value semantics. Implementation of `octave_Foo` as value class is more complicated that needs to care about copy-on-write and reference count. Another option to implement value semantics is (de)serializing the C++ object as Octave data types such as arrays that has its own cost.

There is also a project name [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages but I'm not sure if it works with the recent versions of Octave.

**Octave Part**:

```
# Foo.m
 
classdef Foo < handle

  properties
    m_Foo
  endproperties

  methods

    function obj = Foo (val)
      obj.m_Foo = Foo_dispatch ("constructor", val);
    endfunction

    function Print (obj)
      Foo_dispatch("Print", obj.m_Foo);
    endfunction

  endmethods

endclassdef
```

**C++ part**:

```
// Foo_dispatch.cc

#include <memory>
#include <octave/oct.h>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int n) {/*...*/}
    ~Foo() {/*...*/}
    void Print() {/*...*/}
};

class octave_Foo : public octave_base_value
{
public:

  octave_Foo (): m_data (new Foo (0))
  {}
  
  bool is_defined (void) const
  { return true; }
  
  octave_Foo (int n): m_data (new Foo (n))
  {}
  
  void Print () { m_data->Print (); }

private:

  std::shared_ptr<Foo> m_data;

  DECLARE_OV_BASE_TYPEID_FUNCTIONS_AND_DATA
};

DEFINE_OV_TYPEID_FUNCTIONS_AND_DATA (octave_Foo,
                                     "Foo wrapper",
                                     "octave_Foo");

DEFUN_DLD (Foo_dispatch, args, nargout,
           "Foo_dispatch")
{
  octave_value_list retval;

  std::string method_name = args (0).string_value ();

  if (method_name == "constructor")
    {
      int val = args (1).int_value ();
      
      retval.append (octave_value (new octave_Foo (val)));
    }
  else if (method_name == "Print")
    {
      octave_base_value *object = args (1).internal_rep ();

      octave_Foo *foo = dynamic_cast <octave_Foo *> (object);

      if (! foo)
        error ("expected octave_Foo object!");

      foo->Print ();
    }

  return retval;
}
```