# call nonstatic c++ member function from within Octave

Tags: c++, octave

While it is clear to me how to build a call-interface for a standalone c++ function from within Octave, how can I create a runtime for a class object instance whose member functions are called from within Octave?

Example:

```cpp
// c++ code
#include<octave/oct.h>
struct Foo{
  double y=1;
  double callback(double x){ return y*=x[0]*x[1]*x[2]; }
};
```

```matlab
% Octave code
create_foo();
x = [1,2,3];
y = callback_foo(x); % y=6
y = callback_foo(x); % y=36
```

I am only creating one instance of Foo, but of course I am happy if `create_foo` returns a handle `T` at the object that calls `callback_foo` (cf. below).

```matlab
% Octave code
T = create_foo();
x = [1,2,3];
y = callback_foo(T,x); % y=6
y = callback_foo(T,x); % y=36
```

Comment: Possibly you need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68697643/6579744).